# Is there is problem in my xml?

Tags: xml, spring, xml-namespaces

Spring framework throws error

org.jdom.JDOMException Exception in startElement: NAMESPACE_ERR: An attempt is made to create or change an object in a way which is incorrect with regard to namespaces.

with this XML

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >

    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="*">

    <ns1:response 
        xmlns:ns1="urn:enterprise.soap.acme.com/objs" 
        xmlns="urn:enterprise.soap.acme.com/objs">

        <ns1:Result>
                <ns1:id>1</ns1:id>
                <ns1:success>true</ns1:success>
        </ns1:Result>
    </ns1:response>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I think xmlns="ur... is not correct. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using an updated version?

http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/faq.html#namespace_err